# replacing the last character in a string

Tags: vb.net, string, windows-phone-7

I have another question again about visual basic, the language I am using now in developing apps for windows phone 7.5. My question is how can I replace the last character in a string? Example I have the string "clyde", now I want to replace the last character 'e' with 'o', but how can I do that? Any help would be so appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String str = "clyde";
str = str.Substring(0, str.Length - 1) + 'o';
```

Tried some online VB converter

```
Dim str As String = "clyde"
str = str.Substring(0, str.Length - 1) & "o"C
```

Answer (score 2):

in vb.net script:

```
  Dim s As String

  Sub Main()
    s = "hello world"
    s = s.Substring(0, s.Length - 1)  &  "o"

    Console.WriteLine(s)
    Console.ReadLine()
  End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, you are right! @nkchandra has the correct solution anyway... Fixed it

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: now tested (I forgot to add the namespace

> myString = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(myString, Len(myString) - 1) & myNewChar

example:

> ```
> Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
>     Dim myString As String
>     Dim myChar As String
>     myString = "clyde"
>     myChar = "o"
>     myString = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(myString, Len(myString) - 1) & myChar
>     MsgBox(myString)
> End Sub
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with an Extension of the String Class as described [>>on CodeProject<<](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31260/Extension-Methods-in-VB-NET).

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module StringExtensions

<Extension()> _
Public Function ReplaceFirstChar(str As String, ReplaceBy As String) As String
    Return ReplaceBy & str.Substring(1)
End Function

<Extension()> _
Public Function ReplaceLastChar(str As String, ReplaceBy As String) As String
    Return str.Substring(0, str.Length - 1) & ReplaceBy
End Function

End Module
```

Usage:

```
dim s as String= "xxxxx"
msgbox (s.ReplaceFirstChar("y"))
msgbox (s.ReplaceLastchar ("y"))
```

So I have a simple reuse in my Assembly anywhere... :)

Regards,
Daniel